# Producing mosquitoe buzzing sound with a stick

Tags: waves, frequency

*Male mosquitoes beat their wings 450 to 600 times per second.*

If I take a piece of stick and somehow vibrate it back and forth 500 times per second, does that imitate the buzzing sound of mosquitoes?

Comment: If you replace the idea of a "stick" with a rigid circular disk, and use an electric motor to "vibrate it back and forth", you have made a loudspeaker, which can certainly reproduce the sound of a mosquito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much. The sound you hear is just air vibrations at a certain frequency, which we hear as a note. For example the note A is famously at 440 Hz. Vibrating a stick back and forth at that frequency produces mainly also the same sound.

It will not sound exactly the same because of further frequencies that appear: the specific waveform, and in turn the frequency composition of the tone determines how exactly it sounds. This is the same as that a flute, guitar and mosquito, each playing the same tone, will sound still different.

In fact, a tuning fork is basically a stick that is vibrating back and forth at frequency that is fixed by its length and spring constant.